# Draw a hole in a rectangle with SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

How to draw a hole in a rectangle?
I want to draw a rectangle which has a empty hole inside it and the background can be show.

I am using SKShapeNode to create a rectangle, but I have no idea how to make a hole (circle) inside it.

---

This is what I run your code, but my circle is not empty, the circle is black, I want it to be empty.
Is there any mistake I didn't mention?
[image]

Comment: Take a look at SKCropNode

Comment: Thanks~ SKCropNode works!!

Comment: @Yan-JenHuang 
Hey, could you please share your code with SKCropNode?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let effect = SKEffectNode()
        addChild(effect)

        let rect = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 200))
        rect.fillColor = .green
        effect.addChild(rect)


        let hole = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 40)
        hole.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 100)
        hole.fillColor = .white
        hole.blendMode = .subtract
        rect.addChild(hole)

    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see I create an SKEffectNode. Then I add to it the rectangle. Finally I add the hole to the rectangle.

Comment: I still have some problem here, I want the circle to be empty!

Comment: how to use the .Subtract method?
what is the different if i choose other color to rect or circle

Comment: @Yan-JenHuang: ops... let me check it :D

Comment: @Yan-JenHuang: Fixed! Please take a look.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  All it does is subtract color, ie renders it black.  I want to see what's beneath the green rectangle, like looking through a hole, ie a cutuot.