# Mask SpriteKit swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, mask, skspritenode

I was wondering if it is possible to mask a specific area of a SpriteKitNode in swift. Actually the SKCropNode I am using is not masking the good part of the node. If i could reverse the masking area, it would work.

For example, I have this blue box and I want to mask the middle

[image]

[image]

How can I have this result with SpriteKit.
The blue box is a SKCropNode containing a SKSpriteNode. I actually try to apply a mask to the SKCropNode, but it is not working like I want.

Thank you!

Comment: You want a hole in the middle of the blue box?

Comment: Or you want to show the cropped content of the blue box within the bounds of the white area?

Comment: @Whirlwind I want a whole in the blue box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw a hole in a rectangle with SpriteKit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576112/draw-a-hole-in-a-rectangle-with-spritekit)